# How to echo sum values of different column using where condition with minimum php coding?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have created school exam result database, it consists of different subjects marks viz chemistry1, chemistry2 for 8 examinations. I successfully echoed individual marks value on the same page through selection of class section and subject drop down menu by submit button. I want to show the cumulative result for example pass percentage, average for Male, female, total for all these 8 exams on same page.

I could did this through these type of code

```
$ab50query_am = "SELECT * FROM test_2324 where (chem1_1 >50 AND chem1_1<81) AND cls='$cls_show' AND sex='M' AND (section='$sect_show' )";
$resab50=mysqli_query($db,$ab50query_am);
$ab50val = mysqli_num_rows($resab50);
```

For this i need to use more coding for each category and exam. Is there any array type php script available to achieve this.. awaiting for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think using arrays and loops and aggregates would help you achieve this. Say for example you declare/initialize your arrays like so ...

```
$exams = array('chem1_1', 'chem1_2', 'chem2_1', 'chem2_2', 'chem3_1', 'chem3_2', 'chem4_1', 'chem4_2');
$categories = array('M', 'F', 'Total');
$totals = array_fill_keys($categories, 0);
$counts = array_fill_keys($categories, 0);
```

And then you can maybe loop through in this way

```
    $whereCondition = "(cls='$cls_show' AND section='$sect_show') AND (";
foreach ($exams as $index => $exam) {
    if ($index !== 0) {
        $whereCondition .= " OR ";
    }
    $whereCondition .= "($exam > 50 AND $exam < 81)";
}
$whereCondition .= ")";

$query = "SELECT sex, COUNT(*) AS count, AVG((chem1_1 + chem1_2 + chem2_1 + chem2_2 + chem3_1 + chem3_2 + chem4_1 + chem4_2) / 8) AS average,
          (SUM(chem1_1 > 50 AND chem1_1 < 81) + SUM(chem1_2 > 50 AND chem1_2 < 81) + SUM(chem2_1 > 50 AND chem2_1 < 81) + SUM(chem2_2 > 50 AND chem2_2 < 81) +
           SUM(chem3_1 > 50 AND chem3_1 < 81) + SUM(chem3_2 > 50 AND chem3_2 < 81) + SUM(chem4_1 > 50 AND chem4_1 < 81) + SUM(chem4_2 > 50 AND chem4_2 < 81)) AS pass_count
          FROM test_2324 WHERE $whereCondition GROUP BY sex";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $category = $row['sex'];
    $count = $row['count'];
    $passCount = $row['pass_count'];

    $totals[$category] += $passCount;
    $counts[$category] += $count;
}

$passPercentage = array();
$average = array();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $passPercentage[$category] = ($totals[$category] / ($counts[$category] * count($exams))) * 100;
    $average[$category] = $totals[$category] / $counts[$category];
}
```

You can then echo the values as and where desired on the same page.